# Sorting nodes in a directed graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, matrix, graph

What is the best way to sort nodes for a directed graph? I already made an algorithm with an array A of arrays B, where the elements of array A represent the column and the position of the elements in array B represent the rows. Then the nodes are placed in a grid depending of the positioning in array A and array B (f.e. if the node is in an array B, which is on position 2 of array A and in position 3 of array B then it will get sorted in column 2 and row 3 and rendered there). The columns were decided based on if they are root nodes if the previously found rootnodes are removed.

Because the sorting of the rows is random, you can imagine that the graph does not look all too ideal and orderly.

The graph itself does not have loops, and basically is a tree, with the difference, that one childnode can have multiple parent nodes.

Me and my teammate are struggling to find a way to best sort the rows, so the graph looks most orderly.
We tried to find a library, which might just sort our nodes in a nice way, but we didnt find anything so far, which is why we now try to find a solution ourselves.

First idea was, that we decide the rows based on the row of the parent nodes. But then it can become quite complicated with edgecases, where there is a lot of connections between parentnodes and childnodes, both a parent having mutliple children and a child having multiple parents.

*Our code simply gets an array of nodes and edges. These are then sorted into columns based on their parent nodes and their hierarchy in the tree.*

*Now we need to sort them vertically so that the edges don't overlap, where possible.*

**nodeData.test.js**

```js
it('gets root node array and puts it in a grouped array, simpler test', () => {
    expect(
        getSortedNodes(
            // nodes:
            [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
            // edges:
            [
                { target: 3, source: 2 },
                { target: 3, source: 1 },
            ]
        )
    ).toStrictEqual([[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }], [{ id: 3 }]]) // resulting matrix
})
```

**nodeData.js**

```js
//parameters when called: accumulated is an empty array, rootIds needs to be
//arrays of root Ids (which need to be extracted from nodes before calling function)
//edges is an array of edges, which contain source and target IDs
//thus this function is private and should only be called in getSortedNodes()
function sortNodes(accumulated, nodes, nodeIds, edges) {
    if (!nodeIds.length) {
        return accumulated
    }
    const targetList = edges.map(({ target }) => target)
    const rootIdLayer = difference(nodeIds, targetList, true)
    const rootNodes = nodes.filter(node => rootIdLayer.includes(node.id))
    const accumulatedList = [...accumulated]
    accumulatedList.push(rootNodes)
    const remainingNodeIds = difference(nodeIds, rootIdLayer, true)
    const remainingEdges = edges.filter(edge => !rootIdLayer.includes(edge.source))
    return sortNodes(accumulatedList, nodes, remainingNodeIds, remainingEdges)
}

// parameters take arrays or nodes and edges
// gives out sorted Array of nodes, which can be used to position those in a grid
export function getSortedNodes(nodes, edges) {
    const nodeIds = nodes.map(({ id }) => id)
    return sortNodes([], nodes, nodeIds, edges)
}
```

[image: rendered graph]

Instead of a randomly aligned matrix (see unit test) we intend to have a matrix that has child nodes closer to their parents.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate. 3 is the child of 2 and 4 is the child of 3.

```js
nodes: 

[1,2,3,4]

edges:

[
    {source: 2, target: 3},
    {source: 3, target: 4}
]

expected result:

[
    [1, 2],
    [null, 3],
    [null, 4]
]
```

Current, ugly graph:

[image]

Intended graph where parents are next to children:

[image]

This can get a lot more complex when edges cross.

---

Update: We have decided that we will try the [Sugiyama method](https://blog.disy.net/sugiyama-method/). We will provide an update once we have a result. Additionally, we will provide an answer if we are successful.

If you have any more suggestions or libraries that we could try, feel free to comment or answer!

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to understand your question. I suggest you provide some data structure of your data and different examples of the sorting you want to achieve.

Comment: added some pseudocode to the bottom for illustration purposes. is it better now?

Comment: Better. But I still don't understand what the logic is to get the expected result. What is the meaning of the expected result?

Comment: added some images to explain things.

Comment: There's a bunch of libraries that compute graph layouts with lots of bells and whistles configuration... did you consider using a layout library (optionally using them for rendering too) ?

Comment: I understand more now. However, the definition of ```child nodes closer to their parents.```  is not clear. let's say one parent node can link to 3 children nodes and how do you define which children node supposed to be closer to the parent node?

Comment: > *"let's say one parent node can link to 3 children nodes and how do you define which children node supposed to be closer to the parent node?"* - 

We don't know. Any approach that lines up children with their parents would be better than our current approach. Bonus points if it avoids crossing edges.

Comment: > *"did you consider using a layout library"* - We did find lots of graph libraries, all of them rendering the graph themselves. They always used a canvas which offered extremely limited and poor customization options. None had the features we wanted. We were not able to find a library that exposes its utility functions (like calculating which nodes should be aligned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using `dagre` to get the coordinates of all nodes. This allowed us to remove all of our positioning and sorting code and simply use the coordinates that `dagre` provides.

```
import { graphlib, layout } from 'dagre'

const jsonToGraph = (nodes, edges) => {
    let graph = new graphlib.Graph({ directed: true })

    graph.setGraph({})
    graph.graph().rankDir = 'LR'
    graph.graph().ranksep = '60'

    graph.setDefaultEdgeLabel(function () {
        return {}
    })

    nodes.forEach(({ id, ...attributes }) => {
        graph.setNode(id, attributes)
    })

    edges.forEach(({ source, target, caption, visible }) => {
        graph.setEdge(source, target, { label: caption })
    })

    layout(graph)

    return graph
}
export default jsonToGraph
```

This is how we retrieve the coordinates of each node:

```
const { x, y, caption, type } = graph._nodes[id]
```